# Julia how to make a function dispatch when the input argument is the type itself?

Tags: julia

I want to make a dispatch that creates arrays of different types and sizes with a special intialization for various combinations (so say `zeros(...)` if `inputtype<:Number`, specific chars or strings if `inputtype<:Char` or `inputtype<:AbstractString` etc.

So the idea is to create a dispatch of the type:

```
CreateStaticArray(inputtype::Type, dims::Integer) = ...<create initialized array>
```

which gets the type and dimensions and generates a relevant array. I am interested in using the StaticArrays package, which is why the name is `CreateStaticArray`.
How do I make the second piece which only gets a specific DataType (such as Number, String, etc.) ?

So for example, if `inputtype<:Number` I want the second piece to be:

```
??? = MArray{Tuple{dims...},inputtype}(zeros(inputtype,dims))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match on a type as an argument using `::Type{NameOfType}`. Here, since we need the type within the function body (as an argument to `zeros` in the `Number` case), and we want that to work for any subtype of `Number`, we can use a type variable `T` instead and constrain that:

```
julia> function createstaticarray(::Type{T}, dims::Integer) where {T <: Number} 
           zeros(MArray{Tuple{dims...}, T})
       end
createstaticarray (generic function with 1 method)

julia> createstaticarray(Int, 4)
4-element MVector{4, Int64} with indices SOneTo(4):
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As @SundarR showed, you use `::Type{MyTypeName}` to dispatch on types. In your case, this seems like an unnecessary detour. StaticArrays are already compatible with many array creation methods, which make your function redundant.

For example (these all work for SArrays as well as MArrays):

```
julia> zeros(MMatrix{2,2,Float32})
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> zero(MMatrix{2,2,Float32})  # the same as zeros
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> ones(MMatrix{2,2,Float32})
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> one(MMatrix{2,2,Float32})  # 'matrix one', i.e. an identity matrix
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 1.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0

julia> rand(MMatrix{2,2,Float32})
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 0.370467  0.686029
 0.612083  0.521114

julia> MMatrix{2,2,Float32}(undef) # un-initialized values
2×2 MMatrix{2, 2, Float32, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 3.0f-45  3.50671f-31
 0.0      4.5915f-41
```

Then there are macro-based approaches (`@SArray`, `@MArray`, `@SVector`, etc...):

```
julia> @SMatrix fill(5f0, 2,3)
2×3 SMatrix{2, 3, Float32, 6} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(3):
 5.0  5.0  5.0
 5.0  5.0  5.0

julia> @SVector [i^2 for i in 1:3]
3-element SVector{3, Int64} with indices SOneTo(3):
 1
 4
 9
```

etc.

One extra remark, @TheWitestOfFangs, the last part of the code, which you wanted:

> `??? = MArray{Tuple{dims...},inputtype}(zeros(inputtype,dims))`

has a serious performance issue. It first creates a regular array of zeros, using `zeros(inputtype,dims)`, and then converts it to a StaticArray. You will find that this is much (an order of magnitude) slower than directly creating a StaticArray, such as @SundarR's and my solutions show.

Comment: I assume `SOneTo()` is the StaticArray equivalent of `OneTo()`. If I have `OneTo()` or other `UnitRange` types already used, is there a point (or need) to convert them or change the creation point to `SOneTo()`?

Comment: Correct. Whether you need to use `SOneTo` depends on what you want them for, they can be useful in some cases.